# Returning rows with the same ID but exclude some on second column

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I've seen similar questions about but not quite hitting the nail on the head for what I need. Lets say I have a table.

```
+-----+-------+
| ID  | Value |
+-----+-------+
| 123 |     1 |
| 123 |     2 |
| 123 |     3 |
| 456 |     1 |
| 456 |     2 |
| 456 |     4 |
| 789 |     1 |
| 789 |     2 |
+-----+-------+
```

I want to return DISTINCT IDs but exclude those that have a certain value. For example lets say I don't want any IDs that have a 3 as a value. My results should look like.

```
+-----+
| ID  | 
+-----+
| 456 |
| 789 |
+-----+
```

I hope this makes sense. If more information is needed please ask and if this has been answered before please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when value = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of "3"s for each id.  The `= 0` returns only returns groups where the count is 0 (i.e. there are no "3"s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select distinct t.id
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.value = 3);
```

Comment: This would return 5 rows (all three for 456 and two for 789), yet the op wants just two rows. DISTINCT or GROUP BY can fix that, but then using HAVING becomes more enticing. May be worth explaining that this approach May be faster if the percentage of excluded IDs is high, or the number of rows being aggregated is high?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id from tablename
group by id
having (case when value=3 then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Comment: No need to do select distinct since the group by returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EXCEPT for comparing following two data sets that will give the desired result set

```
select distinct Id from ValuesTbl
except
select Id from ValuesTbl where Value = 3
```